# Use Lodash to find a property within a nested array as well as other operations

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using Lodash and the following sample data array of objects, which also contains a nested array, how can I:

1. find the name "`Child-A`" within the `children array` ?
2. having found the name "`Child-A`" within the `children array, determine if it has the property`admin: "Y"` ?
3. based on item 2, remove the actual property `admin: "Y"` from the children array (nested)?

```
data = [
  {
   name: "A",
   type: "AA",
   children: [ { id: 1, name: "Child-A", admin: ["Y"] }],
   other: "NA"
  },
  {
   name: "B",
   type: "BB",
   children: [ { id: 2, name: "Child-B" }],
   other: "NA"
  },
  {
   name: "C",
   type: "CC",
   children: [ { id: 3, name: "Child-C" }],
   other: "NA"
  }
]
```

I am new to Lodash having tried `_.find()` and `_.get()`.

I have tried:

```
const theChild = _.find(data.children, {'name': childName});
```

and from this, I get back `undefined`

Comment: Smells like homework... Why would you need Lodash for that? A simple JS `.find()` is enough, no need to load a library. I am happy to give you the solution if you're stuck somewhere, but not to do your homework :) What have you tried?

Comment: @JeremyThille seriously not homework at all. Have the lodash library loaded for other operations.

Comment: Ah, alright then, because that looks really generic, with a library as prerequisite. Fine, I'll write an answer

Comment: You should post what you've tried nonetheless

Comment: @JeremyThille have provided what I tried above.

Comment: Good, fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Lodash, some say it's great, but so far I've managed to do this kind of object manipulation with pure JS, so here goes :

(I did everything in one go, finding the object, checking if it has the admin property, removing it.)

```js
let data = [{
    name: "A",
    type: "AA",
    children: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Child-A",
      admin: ["Y"]
    }],
    other: "NA"
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    type: "BB",
    children: [{
      id: 2,
      name: "Child-B"
    }],
    other: "NA"
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    type: "CC",
    children: [{
      id: 3,
      name: "Child-C"
    }],
    other: "NA"
  }
]

data = data.map(obj => {
  obj.children = obj.children.map( child => {
      if(child.name !== "Child-A") return child;
      let hasY = child.admin && child.admin.includes("Y");
      console.log("Has admin==='Y' : ", hasY);
      delete child.admin;
      return child;
  })
  return obj;
})

console.log("Transformed data = ", data)
```

Comment: I've realised I made a mistake in my data format, which I have updated above. children record should've been: children: [ { id: 1, name: "Child-A", admin: ["Y"] }], Getting undefined as part of your let hasY

Comment: out of curiosity as I'm not sure if I will need this but how would I add the property admin: ["Y"] to B.children? Thanks.

Comment: `child.admin = ["Y"]` :) instead of `delete child.admin`

Comment: Thanks. Just letting you know that I also needed to add the condition (typeof child !== 'undefined')

Comment: No, you don't need to, because `map` iterates every element in the array, so if there are 5 elements, each of them will necessarily be defined.

Answer (score 1):

love lodash, [learn lodash](https://smile.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_10?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lodash%20essentials&sprefix=lodash%20ess%2Caps%2C222&crid=17YF3YP6MJCQ7)...

```
_.forEach(data, (d, i) => {
  let fIdx= _.findIndex(d.children, {'name': 'Child-A', 'admin': ['Y']});
  if(fIdx > -1) delete data[i].children[fIdx].admin;
});
```

**Note**: this will find all instances of your condition